# Can I use a .NETFramework project within a .NETCoreApp project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am building out a website using WebAPI in .NETCoreApp v1.0.  However, I am trying to connect to an API for blackbook which is in another project that is built in .NETFramework v4.5.

When I attempt to add a reference to it in Reference Manager I get the following error:

> The following projects are not supported as references:
>
> - BlackbookWCFProxy has target frameworks that are incompatible with targets in current project MainProject.
>
> MainProject:
>
> .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
>
> BlackbookWCFProxy:
>
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.5

So does that mean I have to scrap my entire project because a single API was built in .NETFramework? What about the other APIs I want to use?  How can I get it to work nicely with my project?

Comment: Is `BlackbookWCFProxy` a class you have written yourself? And is it just a client to an WCF Service? If it's just WCF Client classes generated, you can use https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/25/announcing-wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-rc2-and-asp-net-core-rc2/ to generate a .NET Compatible WCF proxy client from a WCF endpoint! But you can't use existing WCF proxies. But hosting WCF services isn't support on .NET Core yet (and may never be)

Comment: It can be downloaded here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c3b3666e-a928-4136-9346-22e30c949c08

Comment: I did not build it.  It was built before my time. However I do not have the time to rebuild it, so I have to implement it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should install .NET Core RTM to make a .net core project so you will find this on following [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/installing-net-core-rtm/)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this.  My main project is already .NET Core, and I am trying to load a .NETFramework project within it.

Comment: sorry i think you want to make project in .net core.